# String Date Ordering: Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to write a custom logic(if at all its possible in Sequelize) where the data I have is in the following format:

```
["Apr 2013", "Aug 2018", "Jan 2014", .....]
```

These are month and years, but in string format. Because of which, Sequelize orders them in alphabetical order. But, I want to order them how dates are ordered.

How can I do this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In general, convert the date strings into YYYYMMDD string format. Then the items can be lexicographically sorted. In your case you can do YYYYMM string format.

```
dates = ["Apr 2013", "Aug 2018", "Jan 2014"];

function ConvertDate(dateStr) {
  let mon = dateStr.substring(0,3);
  let year = dateStr.substring(5,4);

  let month = 0;
  if(mon == "Jan")
    month = 1;
  else if(mon == "Feb")
    month = 2;
  ... and so on

  return `${year}${month.padStart(2,0)}`
}

sorted = dates.map(x => { dateStr: x, sortKey: ConvertDate(x) })
   .sort(function(a, b) {
           if (a.sortKey < b.sortKey) {
             return -1;
           }
           if (a.sortKey > b.sortKey) {
             return 1;
           }

           // must be equal
           return 0;
         }
     );

// now the array 'sorted' has the dates sorted
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this using Sequelize. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Sorry. I am not familiar with sequelize.js. However, a quick reading of the documentation shows, this must accomplish what you want. Assumes your date strings are in col1 and ConvertDate is as defined earlier.

dates.findAll({
  order: [
    // Will order by  ConvertDate(`col1`) DESC
    [sequelize.fn('ConvertDate', sequelize.col('col1'), 'DESC']
  ]
});